# How to use public static final String SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER permission in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions

I want to know what are the other activities launched when my service is running background . 
If there is a new activity launched , then my service should know it . How do i know ? Can i use SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER permission ? How can i use it . Thanks for all the help .

Answer (score 1):

as per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER) it seems it is only for `debug` mode.

**UPDATE**

as per this [**THREAD**](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3af09c76f3ba8d96/d314c4adaaa217c4?show_docid=d314c4adaaa217c4&pli=1) your listed permission is a system which the android team `forgot to cleanup` in the release and it is just lying there.

**EIDT**

i guess `polling` (check in intervals) is the only way left for you. check this [**thread**](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/detect-home-key-pressed-t49865.html). you may be able to use the [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) to find the running apps.

Comment: yeah looks that way . Any other suggestion how i can know what activity is launched from the service which is running in foreground ?

Comment: @Preethi: your comment is not clear. do you want to monitor activities of your application only. or all the applications in the system.

Comment: @ Sam , I want to monitor the applications in the system , Know when the user presses the home key i.e the activity is Home activity . Basically i want to know the activities running globally . Any clue ? I have a broadcast receiver and then i start the service so i have no clue if user presses the home key .

Comment: @Preethi there is an [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) class in which you can get the list of running applications. and there is a way to detect homekey press within an activity. if you register for launcher permissions you can detect homekey (longpress i guess). but from outside an activity detecting homekey is not possible (to the best of my knowledge).